# Laravel 5.4 View [name] not found

Tags: php, vagrant, homestead, laravel-5.4

Even if the views is available at the resources/views directory laravel is showing me this error

**View [name] not found.**

Everything was working fine until a token mismatch error occured currently i am not being able to access any view in the views directory.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});//in web.php
```

is throwing **View [welcome] not found.** exception

**NOTE**
I am running my application vagrant in homestead

Comment: i hope welcome file is not in a folder

Comment: welcome.blade.php is available in the folder resources/views

Comment: delete all the files in `storage\framework\cache`, `storage\framework\session` and `storage\framework\veiws` and try again

Comment: can you send a photo of your view folder???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having this problem only when running the application on homestead server and i was able to solve this after i ran the

```
php artisan config:clear
```

command

Answer (score 4):

First of all check `welcome` view exist in the `resources/views` directory. After that run following command on terminal:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

and refresh the page.

**Explanation:** Laravel maintains cache to serve view, so you have to clear the cache.

Comment: the view "welcome.blade.php" does exists in the resources/views directory and i have also tried the cache clear command this does not fix my problem

Comment: **the view "welcome.blade.php" does exists in the resources/views directory** then make it.

Answer (score 0):

check your blade syntax, i just fix mine
it was

```
@if
@component
@endif
@endcomponent
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on the server. The cause was folders inside the view folder has no executable permission. After giving permission to those folders everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

none of above answers helped me.
Heres what i did.
The issue is that laravel cant find new route provided by your in web.php because it is using it from cached routes. So try running this command

```
php artisan route:cache
```

This will clear routes cache
Hopefully this will solve your issue