# View [shared.view] not found. (View: 'dir') in laravel 5.4 on local machine

Tags: php, iis, laravel-5.4

Please help with the query mentioned in the subject line, I've tried the following:

```
<!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42505607/laravel-5-4-view-name-not-found -->
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache

<!-- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/view-home-not-found?page=1 -->
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer update

<!-- Partial view folder structure -->
- fares-and-payments.blade.php (this is the view that includes wc-fares-and-payments.balde.php)
- shared
-- rail-routes.blade.php
-- wc-fares-and-payments.balde.php
```

@yoeunes gives me the following error when doing php artisan route:cache, wtf haven't touched anything to do with login:

```
[LogicException]
Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.
```

I'm running PHP on IIS and not Apache if that helps, and I did notice that IIS was acting strangely last week (giving me HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found), do you think that maybe sorting the IIS issue might resolve this?

Comment: did you tried `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: @yoeunes just tried it now and still giving the same result, do I need to do `composer update` after `php artisan view:clear`, as I didn't do that though?

Comment: can you please provice your views folder structure, and you return view line,  what does it return when you give another view name that also exists

Comment: It's fine when I give another view that exists in the shared folder, but will update my question to include my view folder structure.

Comment: can you please check if you have a `view.blade.php` under your `shared` folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error also occurs when you try to move the whole project directory to other path. run the following commands:

```
php artisan optimize --force
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

also This happens when Laravel doesn't find a view file in your application. Make sure you have a file named: `view.blade.php` under your `resources/views/shared` directory.

Note that Laravel will do the following when calling `return view('shared.view')`:

- For `view('view')` Laravel will look for the file:
  `resources/views/view.php`.
- For `view('shared.view')` Laravel will look for the file:
  `resources/views/shared/view.blade.php`.

Comment: please see my update, and thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @TimothyKruger just re-run these commands with clear instead of cache, it will solve your problem

Comment: Nope unfortunately it's still giving me the same error :-(, wtf x 2.

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as the correct one as I think in 90% of the cases your solution would work.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to say thanks again to @yoeunes for all the help yesterday re this issue, and I finally managed to figure out the cause of the problem.

The reason why it was throwing an exception as mentioned in my op was because somehow when I copied and pasted the name of the view from Sublime Text and then renamed my view in the shared folder, it somehow must have added a space to the end of the file, or maybe an invisible special character and that's why it wasn't working.

I managed to rectify this by renaming the file manually in windows explorer.